# CUDA efficient polygons fill algorithm

Tags: algorithm, cuda, gpgpu, fill, polygons

I need efficient fill algorithm to fill closed polygons (like ex. Scanline fill), which I can run on CUDA. Have you got any suggestions?

Thanks in advance for any replays!

Comment: What do you mean by efficient? What ratio close to the performance of GPU HW rasterizers? Should the algorithm be fully general purpose/ VS specialized for small triangles etc. Be precise!

Comment: Thanks for answer. Here's what I need to do: I've got a scene of a few cuboids (some of them overlapping). I need to render them on a plane and fill them inside as fast as possible - that's why I thought about CUDA. I'd appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: It might be better to put your geometry in a Vertex Buffer Object and rasterize it with OpenGL instead.

Answer (score 2):

[Thrust](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/source/browse/thrust/detail/backend/cuda/scan.h?spec=svn14c236de4360b5e4df97ae92e2c70b7ec4417cdc&r=14c236de4360b5e4df97ae92e2c70b7ec4417cdc) has a really good scanning algorithm, but only along single line. You may need to extend it a bit to work with images. Assuming edges are 1 and 0 everywhere else, all you need to do is perform a prefix sum on the image. Once the prefix sum is complete, all you need to do is fill the areas where the sum is Odd.

Comment: This would not necessarily work, imagine you'd have a single pixel are the image corner, or two pixels at the top corner of the polygon.